# Methods for testing the posibility of some action?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics

Suppose a thing T needs to do an action (or change in the environment) A.

Then A must be able to be composed of some posible actions A_1, A_2, ..., A_N.

But I am using the definition of posible recursively, like so: *For the action A to be posible [...] A_1, A_2, ..., A_N must be too.* But this implies that for A_1 to be posible A_11, A_12, ... A_1M must be too, going so inside a spiral with no end, not having the chance to properly define A.

My conclusion is that there must be some actions which are posible by definition, and all other actions are combinations of them. If there is no definition for such actions, I think there should be some axioms that all posible actions obey, but the imposible ones not. Any light on this would be great. Thanks.

Footnote: I didnt know which tag to put.

Comment: What do "thing" and "action" mean in your question?

Comment: @virmaior Action: change in environment. Thing: Just suppose it is a human being.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a philosophy question, and I'm double not sure that it's anything more than 'am I right?' which is off topic, so I'm gonna have to vote to close. But because it might be helpful, I think what you're thinking about is just how physics works. We understand that there are four fundamental forces and every other interaction (that we know of) is comprised of those four forces interacting. They are the bedrock and every other interaction is based off of them. This is a physicalist view in philosophy, so not everyone agrees with it, but it fits your definition.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into the much larger issue that it's almost impossible to accurately assign probability in real life. Even determining the probability that the sun will rise tomorrow is philosophically complicated: [Sunrise Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem).

If you break an event down into subevents, know the probability of those subevents and the interdependence between them, you can indeed compute the probability of the main event.

In this case, however, all you've done is move the problem "down" one step. You now have subevents whose probability you don't know. You can continue breaking down these subevents further, but you'll just end up with a large number of simple events whose probability you don't know.

Mathematicians (and pure statisticians) work around this problem by using the word "assume" a lot: assume a fair die/coin, assume a random sample/draw, assume people respond accurately to polls, etc.

Probability can tell you: if we make certain assumptions, we can compute the probability of something happening. However, these assumptions may or may not apply in the real world.

Ultimately, probability answers the question: if we were to repeat this experiment repeatedly, how often would various outcomes occur as we increased the number of trials.

In the real world, you never really get to repeat an experiment for the same reason you can't cross the same river twice: the real world is in a constant state of flux, and conditions are never identical twice.

Comment: You are confusing probable with posible. Posible is something with non zero probability.

Comment: You might be right. Are you asking if a given event has a non-zero probability of occurring (ie, that it's "possible")?

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Comment: I think you could still apply my answer, except your final goal would be to determine if the probability of an event is 0% or greater than 0%. In the real world, I'm not sure you can assign a 0% probability to any meaningful event, so all (nontrivially false) things are possible, even if they may be very improbable.

Comment: What are the trivially false ones? That is another form of the question. Is there any?